# Sending POST parameters - Retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

I 'm new to retrofit, and I 'm trying to implement a retrofit project.

I'm using the POST method, and passing in the body : { "text ": " SURC "}
But nothing is coming to the server and gives me an error

Data.class

```
public class Data {
    String text;

    public Data(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Interface

```
public interface RecordService {
        @POST("/test")
        void post(@Body Data data, Callback<List<Record>> callback);
}
```

Main

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization",
                        "Bearer fb5JnZnlG3pyk3oaeSMNXRiuBHH2Abch8GwUhFPM");
            }
        };


    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.pe/example")
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                @Override
                public void log(String msg) {
                    Log.i("Log Retrofit", msg);
                }
            })
            .build();

Data data = new Data("surc");

    RecordService record = restAdapter.create(RecordService.class);
    record.postUbigeo(data, new Callback<List<Record>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Record> records, Response response) {
            Log.i("dataaa success", response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.i("dataaa failure", error.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
```

Error in server

```
I/Log Retrofit: {"_meta":{"status":"ERROR"},"records":{"errorCode":1002,"userMessage":"Error Params","devMessage":[],"more":{"fields":{"text":"text is required"}},"applicationCode":[]}}
```

[image]

Log:

```
I/Log Retrofit: ---> HTTP POST http://api.pe/example/test
I/Log Retrofit: Authorization: Bearer fb5JnZnlG3pyk3oaeSMNXRiuBHH2Abch8GwUhFPM
I/Log Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
I/Log Retrofit: Content-Length: 16
I/Log Retrofit: {"text":"surc"}
I/Log Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (16-byte body)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2c3a59c6 time:772594491
I/Log Retrofit: <--- HTTP 500 http://api.pe/example/test (421ms)
I/Log Retrofit: Server: nginx
I/Log Retrofit: Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 16:41:57 GMT
I/Log Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json
I/Log Retrofit: Content-Length: 172
I/Log Retrofit: Connection: keep-alive
I/Log Retrofit: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.21 ZendServer/6.2.0
I/Log Retrofit: Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
I/Log Retrofit: Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aemfb488cu0bk5n05i7ug45ak1ia94cg; path=/
I/Log Retrofit: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
I/Log Retrofit: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
I/Log Retrofit: Pragma: no-cache
I/Log Retrofit: Status: 1002 Input Parameter not valid
I/Log Retrofit: E-Tag: 1e9672f97d6b00dace015a629dcb67ec
I/Log Retrofit: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
I/Log Retrofit: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1449074516360
I/Log Retrofit: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1449074516514
I/Log Retrofit: {"_meta":{"status":"ERROR"},"records":{"errorCode":1002,"userMessage":"Error Params","devMessage":[],"more":{"fields":{"text":"text is required"}},"applicationCode":[]}}
I/Log Retrofit: <--- END HTTP (172-byte body)
I/dataaa failure: 500 Internal Server Error
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2c3a59c6 time:772595639
```

Postman:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I forget, but I add the code

Comment: Why not using `@Field("text") String yourText` ?

Comment: Also `@Header("Authorization") String token` instead of intercepting and Adding header ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to post like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("text", "SURC");
record.postUbigeo(data, new Callback<List<Record>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Record> records, Response response) {
            Log.i("dataaa success", response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.i("dataaa failure", error.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
```